# finding the number of pairs of integers that satisfies 2 equations

Tags: python, math

I have an equation for my review:

> The number of pairs of integers (x and y) that satisfy both `x**2+y**2 <= 36`
>   and `y = x - 4` is either 4, 5, 6, 7 or 8?

The teacher said if one can create a script for it, they shall receive extra marks.

I tried my best using python:

```
a = [[y+4, y] for y in xrange(100) if ((y+4)^2)+(y^2) <= 36] #I tried 100 just to test.
```

But when I try that, it gives 17 answers. I am looking for a way that this will give an answer specified (4, 5, 6, 7 or 8). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `^` with `**`, which is the correct operator for exponentiation.

Also, you might want to put y in the range [-2, 6] since there are only 2 positive integer pairs that satisfy your condition (but nothing forbids negative integers, right?). Try:

```
>>>    [(y-4, y) for y in range(-2, 7) if (y-4)**2 + y**2 <= 36]
>>>    # answers here
```

Comment: Thanks! I completely forgot that.

Comment: @TheOnlyOneAround No problem! Take a look at my edit as well.

Comment: I see, I was wondering why I could get more than 2 answers, forgot that negative integers can also be part of the answer too.

Comment: Yeap! And of course any of the `x,y`'s absolute values are bounded from the square root of 36, which explains the `-2,6` as starting and ending values of the range.

Answer (score 0):

in python `^` is Bitwise Exclusive operator     a ^ b

for exponent you need to use `**`

it should be:

```
a = [[y+4, y] for y in xrange(100) if ((y+4)**2)+(y**2) <= 36]
```